# Personal Block List overwriting text in search results

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I have been using the Chrome Extension [Personal Block List](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) from Google for quite some time. In the recent past, however, it has been having display issues in search results.

[image: screen shot]

As you can see in the screen shot, the added link to block is no longer next to the URL fragment, but has been pushed down to the next line and is written over the text for the description. I see this on every computer (Windows 7 or 8). (Chrome the latest version in the release channel; currently version 32.)

Obviously this is some sort of CSS issue. I suspect that the extension has just been neglected (it was last updated in August, 2012) and hasn't kept up with changes to Google's search results pages. Is there anything I can do to fix it? I would prefer to keep the extension (I do use it occasionally) but this obviously reduces the utility of the search results.

Comment: I am having the same issue, works fine on my XP machines.  Hope they fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extension directory in windows

> \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Extensions\nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef\

edit content_script.js (line 226 before "blockLinkDiv.appendChild(blockLink)")

add:

```
  blockLinkDiv.style.float="left";
  blockLinkDiv.style.margin="0px 5px 0px 0px";
  blockLink.style.color="Maroon";
```

Comment: Works a treat, although I think it'll break with a new version of the extension (assuming they don't fix this in the next version). I also had to disable/enable the extension and restart the browser.

Comment: ...and, unfortunately, I'll need to do this on all my computers.